# Modal component with fade-in overlay and dialog disabled until animation ends

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to rewrite one of my JS plugins to react, as a way of learning.

I have a panel that when hidden/shown needs to be updated with several classnames as well as some that need to wait for a css animation to complete (why the timer).

How should I do this in a react way? Using querySelector to change classnames seem very wrong..?

**Detailed explanation**

When showPanel is triggered the following need to happen

- the body/html element need updated css (hence me adding classes)
- an existing overlay fades in (adding a class to that)
- the modal div is displayed (adding a class for that)
- the modal div is told to be active AFTER the animation has been run (hence the timer and class "am-animation-done")

What I preferably would like to have/learn is best practice to do this in reactjs. I'm thinking a toggle state that when triggered sets the state to visible/hidden and if set to "visible" the class changes below happens. My biggest issue is the timer thing.

```
  showPanel = () => {
            document.querySelector('body').classList.add('am-modal-locked');
            document.querySelector('html').classList.add('am-modal-locked');
            document.querySelector('.am-overlay').classList.add('fadein');
            document.querySelector('.am-modal').classList.add('am-show');

            const timer = setTimeout(() => {
                document.querySelector('.am-modal').classList.add('am-animation-done');
            }, 500);
            return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  hidePanel = () => {
            document.querySelector('.am-modal').classList.remove('am-show');
            document.querySelector('.am-modal').classList.remove('am-animation-done');
            document.querySelector('.am-overlay').classList.add('fadeout');

            const timer = setTimeout(() => {
                document.querySelector('.am-overlay').classList.remove('fadein');
                document.querySelector('.am-overlay').classList.remove('fadeout');
                document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('am-modal-locked');
                document.querySelector('html').classList.remove('am-modal-locked');
            }, 500);
            return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    };
```

**Source code updated for clarifaction**

Comment: I need to modify the element that wraps around the whole website content, otherwise the content behind the panel will scroll when I try to scroll the panel itself. It could be another DIV, but it's an element that lives outside the app itself

Comment: my app is only a small part of a website.

Comment: very crowdy thread yeah, I'm thinking of just removing this all together and repost a new question, and remove the body/html part and just focus on classnames and timer ;)

Comment: somewhat. but not completely. But it made me rethink some parts and I re-wrote the code using hooks and classNames-plugin. (I also added a wrapper div and moved the css rules to that element to make it more react-friendly)

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot simpler in React, here's an example with hooks

```
function Panel() {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  const toggleCallback = useCallback(() => setHidden(hidden => !hidden), []);

  const cls = hidden ? 'hide' : 'show';
  return (
    <div className={cls}>
      <button onClick={toggleCallback}>Toggle</>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you're using the ESLint React Hooks plugin, which comes bundled with Create-React-App, you'll receive `exhaustive-deps` linting error for not defining both `hidden` and `setHidden` as dependencies for the `useCallBack` hook.  It's [overkill to use the useCallBack hook](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) without expensive code, anyway.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 `hidden` isn't a dependency here, only `setHidden`...which won't ever change therefore it would be fine to ignore the warning I imagine, although, it's just as fine to put it into the dependencies to avoid it.  On the performance point, good info on `useCallback` but we are most likely talking about negliable cost here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's not a very good way to do it. Instead you should use state variables to toggle your classes as well. There is no need to manually manipulate DOM. The you can set up your timeout inside the callback of your first setState to change state again.

Maybe something like this:

```
class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      class1: 'on',
      class2: 'off'
    }
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({class1: 'off'}, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({class2: 'on'})
      }, 2000)
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {class1, class2} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className={`${class1} ${class2}`} onClick={this.toggle}>Class toggle</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: When people see executable-snippet they expect it to ***actually be*** executable. Consider modifying it if your intention was to showcase some idea in action. Until then, I've changed its format to regular code block.

Comment: At the very least, you have missing `this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this)` within `constructor()` body to make it work.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov You don't need to bind it, it's a private instance method written as an arrow function. It would work just fine.

Comment: That's another issue I need to highlight - you're [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to use arrow notation for class methods.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Buddy, I don't know why you're nitpicking like this. That's not the point of the example. I don't see anything wrong with using that arrow notation for my example of using *DYNAMIC CLASSES USING STATE*. Would you like to review the code further?

Comment: *'...Would you like to review the code further?'* yeah, sure, why not - your `toggle()` event handler does literally nothing - it swaps `on off` within a `className` string for `off on` and that is a kind of thing average user would struggle to notice from visual appearance of a page. One more is that suggesting OP to proceed with his `setTimeout()` solution seems to be a bad piece of advise to those, who aware of synthetic events in general and `onAnimationEnd` in particular. Is that enough, buddy?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov using class instance methods arrow functions in this way is perfectly fine, it's the equivalent to the manual binding, in fact I'd argue manually binding in the constructor is outdated now and you _should_ favour this approach.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Wish you would get sarcasm

Comment: @James : there's a [certain](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1) rationale behind avoiding arrow notation for class methods (and it looks like MDN tutorial promotes that point of view). While saying *'...I'd argue...you should'* did you have some specific arguments to support your position or it's just you feeling more comfortable to avoid awkward `bind`ing (which I also don't use, since prefer function components)?

Comment: @AshkanPourghasem : wish you could support massive blah in your answer body and comments with some working code to keep up some essential discussion, otherwise, don't see the point to proceed.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov few reasons, less code, less housework (lots of people forget to bind), better readability - for most cases, these are far more prevalent benefits over the any negliable performance benefits. In terms of the limitations, yeah if you know these are going to be a problem for you then you can avoid them under those circumstances - but that wouldn't appear to be the case here. It's probably very likely MDN don't use them in the tutorials because they aren't officially released yet? I haven't checked but as far as I can recall the feature is still in stage 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state to dinamically change classnames inside your component

```
className={this.state.isPanelVisible}
```

And maybe instead of setting it as boolean you can set your variable to the class you need at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

React working with virtual DOM so you should play with state and change class of that particular element like below example:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {'active': false, 'class': 'album'};
    }

  handleClick(id) {
    if(this.state.active){
      this.setState({'active': false,'class': 'album'})
    }else{
      this.setState({'active': true,'class': 'active'})
    }
  }

<div className={this.state.class}  onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this.data.id}>
    <p>Data</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In very basic use cases you can write the logic inside of the class itself.

```
<div className={active ? "active" : "disabled"} />
```

In more advanced cases I would suggest to use something like classnames package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

```
<div className={classNames({ foo: true, bar: true, boo: false })} />
```

Which would result in div having class `foo` and `bar`

This is mainly regarding one component, but if you really have to affect class of something so far away as body would be, than you are most likely gonna need useQuerySelector or put the state somewhere high and then base the logic on it.

Answer (score 0):

use this approach for change styling on state change

```
<div className={`rest_of_classes ${isClassChange ? 'change_class_name': ''}`} />
```